# xfce - How to make the Network Manager applet work in the Status Notifier plugin?

Tags: debian, xfce, networkmanager, plugin

On Xubuntu the *Status Notifier* plugin (pacakge name : `xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin`) works natively, it's the default plugin that manage the *Network Manager* applet, which means it is this plugin that displays the little Wi-Fi icon on the panel.

On Debian XFCE however the default plugin for the *NM* applet is the *Notification Area*.
I'm trying to install the *Status Notifier* plugin on Debian to replace the *Notification Area* but I can't make it work, the plugin doesn't display any item. The [`xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin` documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin) says :

> **Known Issues**
>   Plugin Doesn't Show Any Items
>
> There is already a running service which works with status notifier
>   items. Most probably it's the indicator-application service which is
>   used by xfce4-indicator-plugin. Make sure this service is not running:
>   remove this indicator from xfce4-indicator-plugin and remove the
>   service from autostart.

But I don't understand it. Plus I don't have the same scenario since I don't have the xfce4-indicator plugin installed. In my case I think the problem is the Notification Area.

Answer (score 1):

The two frameworks seem to clash
choose one of the two xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin or xfce4-indicator-plugin

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that the OP states _"I don't have the xfce4-indicator plugin installed"_.